# Can't SSH to ubuntu AWS after creating new user

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-server

Today I tried to ssh to my AWS instance, as usual but got a "Permision denied" error with -v giving me the following:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey 
debug1: Offering RSA public key: localuser@localmachine  
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey  
debug1: Trying private key: serverkey.pem  
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker  
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA  
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey  
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

If I try to log as root@my-ip.com it will authenticate, but show the message: "Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root"."

Last time I logged I created a new user for a web page within a new group "webapps". I assigned the home directory of this user to be the same as the ubuntu user since it was convenient. I have also tried to log in as this user with no success.

Also, I tried generating a new pair of keys (loacally and uploading the public key, and from the AWS console and saving the private key locally).

I would really appreciate if someone can help me!

Edit:

The command I use normally is `ssh -i serverkey.pem ubuntu@my-ip.com` after failing I generated the ssh key locally and uploaded it to AWS and used `ssh ubuntu@my-ip.com` with the key stored at ~/.ssh

Comment: Show your command line (actual command)

Comment: Edited the post to show the command.

Comment: You cannot change the key file for a EC2 Instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling here I think my problem was assigning the second user's home folder to ubuntu's home folder. Since this is insecure it messes with the SSH connection. I had to make another instance and recover the info attaching the old volume to the new server instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the key after created ec2 instance.

Do you have the backup of `serverkey.pem`, if not, you can't login this instance any more. Recreate the ec2 instance with new key is the only way to go.

Comment: I do have the key, I never lost it. I am suspecting it has something to do with assigning a new user and changing permissions on the home folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
debug1: Trying private key: serverkey.pem  
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
```

Did you edit your private key file? Can you check the first line **exactly** is like this?

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: I didn't edit the key, and it does have this (exact copy paste):  `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`